# Cannot execute copy of an original file

Tags: linux

For testing and learning purposes I have made a copy of raspi-config file. 
i can see it in directory and can open it for editing.
However, after saving it with different name I cannot execute it using this command:

```
pi@pi:/ $ sudo raspi-config.test
```

and getting this reply :

```
sudo: raspi-config.test: command not found
```

This is my first attempt to make a copy of Linux file.

Did I missed something to make the file executable?

I have no issues running the original using 
same command sudo file-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In linux it is a "security" issue that you cannot execute scripts and programs in the current directory by default. To do that you must precede
 the script with `./` (dot+slash) so your call should look like this:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ./raspi-config.text
```

It may also be required to make the script executable with

```
rpi ~$ sudo chmod ugo+x raspi-config.text
```

Btw.: It doesn't matter but for convention it is better to name your **sh**ell script `raspi-config.sh`.

Comment: Point taken as far as .sh "suffix"

Comment: OK I cannot accept my own answer, so how to close / mark solved the issue?

Comment: With the accepted answer the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I need to use chmod +x to be able to execute the new file.